# It says that there is an missing terminating character. What should i do?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)

{
   
    int vision;
    
    printf("Rate you court vision: ");
    scanf("%d", &vision");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line with the `scanf` you have &vision with ***double quote at the end***.

Replace this:

`scanf("%d", &vision");`

With this:

`scanf("%d", &vision);`

Answer (score 0):

Read the compiler log carefully, it says:

```
error: missing terminating " character
   11 |   scanf("%d", &vision");
      |                      ^
```

Where the `^` is an arrow pointing at the exact location of the bug.